# Is there a simpler way to simplify the if statement?

Tags: mathematics, shaders, hlsl, graphic-effects

The code below generate angle and radius based brightness gradient. As you can see I need to use 3 if statement to define 3 circle, wonder is there a single code that can create nth circle corresponding to brightness gradient, imagine I want to create 20 circle, using 20 if statement is very unpractical.

```
Shader "Unlit/testDisplay"
{
   Properties
  {
       _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
 }
SubShader
{
    // Render with transparent objects, after the opaque pass.
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
    LOD 100

    // Don't write to the depth buffer.
    ZWrite Off
    // Additive blending (add light/glow).
    Blend One One

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            // Shift our texture coordinates so 0 is in the center,
            // and we go to -2 ... +2 at the edges.
            o.uv = (v.uv -0.5f) *4.0f;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            //Define boundary value for radius
            float radius=length(i.uv);
            if(radius>0&radius<0.5)
            radius=0.5;
            if(radius<1&radius>=0.6)
            radius=1;

            if(radius<1.5&radius>=1.01)
            radius=1.5;

            if(radius<2&radius>=1.51)
            radius=2;

            

            //convert to polar coordinates
            float angle=atan2(i.uv.y,i.uv.x);
            float angle1=frac(angle/(2*3.142f));
            float result=-4*radius+angle1+13*frac(_Time.x);  
            return result;
            
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: What happens when your radius is 0.55?

Comment: Yeah there errors in the code. My guess is that specific boundary would have a  continuous brightness gradient that is proportional to radius rather than a discrete value.I haven't try it out yet

Comment: This kind of code optimization is not specific to game development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the conditions with the modulus operator. All if conditions can be reduced to

```
 radius = radius - (radius % 0.5) + 0.5;
```

The `%` returns the reminder of the calculation.

```
0.4 % 0.5 = 0.4
0.6 % 0.5 = 0.1
0.8 % 0.5 = 0.3
  1 % 0.5 = 0
```

We substract the result from our original radius to get into the correct interval. The last + 0.5 is for shifting the result.

Your original code though has some undefined areas for the radius if for example the value is `0.55`.

Comment: For your proposed method is it  after the line"float radius=length(i.uv);" add in the next line " radius=(radius%0.5)*0.5+0.5;"? I not sure why I got other result. It generate a ripple image. Indeed what you suggested should have return the same boundary value as my original code using the if statement but I also fail to identify what causing a different result 

Comment: @chuackt I made small before coffee mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Repetitive actions very very often means a loop. If you don't know how many repetitions, that almost always **forces** a loop.
To keep the code clean, I suggest a function with the radius as parameters, and 2 more parameters describing your data: the step increment and the number of steps (you could also use the step increment and the maximum radius if you wanted).
The function returns the rounded radius.

```
float getRoundedRadius(float radius, flot stepIncrement, int nbSteps)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nbSteps ; i++)
    {
        if (radius >= i*stepIncrement && radius <= (i+1)*stepIncrement)
            return i*stepIncrement;
    }
}
```

Your function `frag` becomes:

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    //Define boundary value for radius
    float radius= getRoundedRadius(length(i.uv), 0.5, 4);

    //convert to polar coordinates
    float angle=atan2(i.uv.y,i.uv.x);
    float angle1=frac(angle/(2*3.142f));
    float result=-4*radius+angle1+13*frac(_Time.x);  
    return result;
        
}
```